# SSLKeyException: FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - A corrupt or unuseable certificate was received

Tags: web-services, x509certificate, keystore, jdeveloper

I am trying to consume a .NET web service from java client **generated in JDeveloper** IDE. 
I have server and client certificates.  **I successfully call this service in SoupUI, just by specifying *SSL Keystore=client_cert.pfx* for Request.**
I add server certificate to the java keystore by the following command:

> ```
>  keytool -import -alias client_alias -file client_cert.cer
>       -keystore cacerts
> ```

When I try to run my **standalone java client** I get 
**javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - A corrupt or unuseable certificate was received.**

Here is the stacktrace:

> jdk160_21\bin\javaw.exe -client
>   -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=49995 -classpath C:\JDeveloper\777\Application1.adf;C:\JDeveloper\777\Application1\Client\classes;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrf.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\modules\com.oracle.toplink_1.0.0.0_11-1-1-4-0.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\modules\org.eclipse.persistence_1.0.0.0_2-1.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\modules\com.bea.core.antlr.runtime_2.7.7.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\oracle_common\modules\oracle.toplink_11.1.1\javax.persistence_2.0_preview.jar
>   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks
>   -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=<-loopback>|localhost|localhost.localdomain|127.0.0.1|::1-Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
>   -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888 -Dhttps.nonProxyHosts=<-loopback>|localhost|localhost.localdomain|127.0.0.1|::1|
>   client.proxy.WSHttpBinding_IQueryServiceClient Listening for transport
>   dt_socket at address: 49995 Debugger connected to local process.              
>                   
>               
>                    
>        
>        
>        
>         
>     
>      
>   
>          
>                  
>      
>                                           
>             
>               
>    <27042299 SSL3/TLS MAC>  
>      <27042299 received HANDSHAKE>     
>      
>           (Unknown Source)   at
>   com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.HandshakeHandler.handleHandshakeMessages(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.certicom.tls.record.MessageInterpreter.interpretContent(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.certicom.tls.record.MessageInterpreter.decryptMessage(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.processRecord(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readRecord(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readUntilHandshakeComplete(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.completeHandshake(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.certicom.tls.record.WriteHandler.write(Unknown Source)
>     at com.certicom.io.OutputSSLIOStreamWrapper.write(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
>     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
>     at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:123)    at
>   weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:162)
>     at
>   weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:376)
>     at
>   weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:37)
>     at
>   weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:720)
>     at
>   weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:980)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(HttpClientTransport.java:215)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:204)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:124)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:121)
>     at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:866)    at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:815)  at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:778)   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:680)     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:272)     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:153)     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:115)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:95)
>     at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:136)   at
>   $Proxy34.getListForDropdown(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.java:84)
>     at $Proxy35.getListForDropdown(Unknown Source)  at
>   client.proxy.WSHttpBinding_IQueryServiceClient.main(WSHttpBinding_IQueryServiceClient.java:66)
>
> > javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: FATAL
> >     Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - A corrupt or unuseable certificate was
> >     received.     at
> >     com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(HttpClientTransport.java:218)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:204)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:124)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:121)
> >       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:866)    at
> >     com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:815)  at
> >     com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:778)   at
> >     com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:680)     at
> >     com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:272)     at
> >     com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:153)     at
> >     com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:115)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:95)
> >       at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:136)   at
> >     $Proxy34.getListForDropdown(Unknown Source)   at
> >     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> >     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
> >       at
> >     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
> >       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
> >     weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.java:84)
> >       at $Proxy35.getListForDropdown(Unknown Source)  at
> >     client.proxy.WSHttpBinding_IQueryServiceClient.main(WSHttpBinding_IQueryServiceClient.java:66)
> >     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE
> >     - A corrupt or unuseable certificate was received.    at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.fireException(Unknown
> >     Source)   at
> >     com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.fireAlertSent(Unknown
> >     Source)   at
> >     com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.HandshakeHandler.fireAlert(Unknown
> >     Source)   at
> >     com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.HandshakeHandler.handleHandshakeMessages(Unknown
> >     Source)   at
> >     com.certicom.tls.record.MessageInterpreter.interpretContent(Unknown
> >     Source)   at
> >     com.certicom.tls.record.MessageInterpreter.decryptMessage(Unknown
> >     Source)   at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.processRecord(Unknown
> >     Source)   at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readRecord(Unknown
> >     Source)   at
> >     com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readUntilHandshakeComplete(Unknown
> >     Source)   at
> >     com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.completeHandshake(Unknown
> >     Source)   at com.certicom.tls.record.WriteHandler.write(Unknown Source)
> >       at com.certicom.io.OutputSSLIOStreamWrapper.write(Unknown Source)   at
> >     java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
> >       at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
> >       at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:123)    at
> >     weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:162)
> >       at
> >     weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:376)
> >       at
> >     weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:37)
> >       at
> >     weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:965)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(HttpClientTransport.java:215)
> >       ... 20 more

**Please help!** Thanks for any advice you may have.